# detect whether anything has been changed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a page with 3 views, all the 3 views has forms which will be populated from an XML file and will be filled by user. This page has a common save button and cancel button(toolbar menu- primary). On click of save the data is beign saved to xml file, when user clicks cancel

1) if user has done changes on the form(has edited any fields) then a popup(displayalert) should be displayed saying "Do u want to leave the page and discard ur changes?" and depending on the users choice redirect to other page.

2) if user has not done any changes then user would be directly taken back to the desired page.

Now my question here is which event can be used if I want to detect whether anything has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're currently using Bindings for your entries. If not, you should. Look over here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

If you also bind your Cancel-button to a Command, you can perform a check in this action to see if anything has been changed.
Which means, you just check if the binded properties in your ViewModel are changed or not.

Comment: No I am not using Bindings, no other way to do it without bindings?